# Is it possible to run Slither without Hardhat?

Tags: smartcontracts, static-analysis

I have a Foundry project, and I prefer to not install Hardhat.
Would it be possible to run Slither as specified in the [Foundry Book](https://book.getfoundry.sh/config/static-analyzers#slither)?

Currently, if I run at the root folder of my Foundry project:

```bash
slither .
```

I get the error:

```bash
$ slither .                                                                                                                                              
Problem executing hardhat: npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: hardhat                                                                                                
Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported.                                                                                                                     
Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again.                                                                                                                                           
HardhatError: HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported.                                                                                                             
Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again.
```

I am running Slither 0.9.2.

Also, I tried:

```bash
slither . --hardhat-ignore-compile
```

Answer (score 0):

This option made the trick:

```bash
slither . --compile-force-framework foundry
```